# Get all properties of an object using reflection - but only the properties where the object has a value for them (not default value or null)

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, properties

So I'm wanting to return the properties of an object, either generic  or hard coded typeof(User) for e.g

However i only want to return the properties where the object I'm getting the properties for, has a value set against it, not the default value nor null. The reason for this is so that i can use these properties only to build an expression to only check these properties against columns in our database for items.

I tried something like this, however it still brings back all the values,

```
public User AutomatedUser {get;set;} // some properties of this will populated elsewhere

var props = typeof(User).GetProperties()
            .Where(pi => pi.GetValue(AutomatedFromUser) != pi.PropertyType.GetDefault());
```

I then found this method on the forum for getting default values of types, as compiler won't allow != default(pi.PropertyType) as "Pi" is a variable. Method below...

```
public static object GetDefault(this Type type)
    {
        // If no Type was supplied, if the Type was a reference type, or if the Type was a System.Void, return null
        if (type == null || !type.IsValueType || type == typeof(void))
            return null;

        // If the supplied Type has generic parameters, its default value cannot be determined
        if (type.ContainsGenericParameters)
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "{" + MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod() + "} Error:\n\nThe supplied value type <" + type +
                "> contains generic parameters, so the default value cannot be retrieved");

        // If the Type is a primitive type, or if it is another publicly-visible value type (i.e. struct), return a 
        //  default instance of the value type
        if (type.IsPrimitive || !type.IsNotPublic)
        {
            try
            {
                return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(
                    "{" + MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod() + "} Error:\n\nThe Activator.CreateInstance method could not " +
                    "create a default instance of the supplied value type <" + type +
                    "> (Inner Exception message: \"" + e.Message + "\")", e);
            }
        }

        // Fail with exception
        throw new ArgumentException("{" + MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod() + "} Error:\n\nThe supplied value type <" + type +
                                    "> is not a publicly-visible type, so the default value cannot be retrieved");
    }
}
```

Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated as to why this wouldn't be working, or where i'm going wrong.

Comment: Hi rugbylad_28, would you please help to understand where clause  `.Where(pi => pi.GetValue(**AutomatedFromUser**) != pi.PropertyType.GetDefault());` Or please provide expected result with quick sample that helps lot to understand the problem.

Comment: so using reflection i'm getting the properties of the type, but then filter down the properties where the value of the property for my object is not null or default value. 
pi = PropertyInfo object, so pi.GetValue(Object) returns the value for that property from the given object

Comment: Can you please code quick sample with expected .net framework on https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Comment: @MukeshVadodariya i'm not sure how else to explain it , even with code example it'll just be the same code as above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is related to boxing and the fact that `==` performs *reference equality*. Both `PropertyInfo.GetValue` and your `GetDefault` function return `object`, so your value types will be boxed. This means that even if both values are zero, they will be placed into two seperate boxes. Each of those boxes is a different `object` and thus reference equality returns `false`.

Consider the following:

```
object x = 0;
object y = 0;
Console.WriteLine(x == y); // prints False
```

The solution is to call `object.Equals` (either the instance or static version) instead.

```
object x = 0;
object y = 0;
Console.WriteLine(x.Equals(y)); // prints True 
Console.WriteLine(object.Equals(x, y)); // prints True
```

See this [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgIwFgBQiAM64GYAEihSA7PgN7r7WEIIVU1MD2ARgFYCmAxsPgB74AvPkwBuRk2psuvfAE9hoiWik04SAJwAKQUJHyAlCrXUNO/gDoAogEcIAQwA2AZ21Hjkqee0B5DjzANvbObvwANB4mNAC+6DFAA===) demo for an example of both versions.

This means that the solution to your question is the following:

```
var props = typeof(User).GetProperties()
            .Where(pi => 
                !object.Equals(
                    pi.GetValue(AutomatedFromUser),
                    pi.PropertyType.GetDefault()
                ) 
             );
```

We use the static version to guard ourselves against `null` since `null.Equals(...)` would obviously throw. Calling the static method is the same as the instance method *except* that it first checks for reference equality and then guards against nulls. After that it calls [`x.Equals(y)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs,76).

Comment: Thanks for this explanation,  any suggestions on how to handle empty lists in this scenario, as some may be ICollection, List<T>, etc

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The default value of a list *is* null. But if you determine that it's "default" if it's empty you could use `if (pi.GetValue(AutomatedFromUser) is ICollection c && c.Count == 0){ /*default*/ }` to determine you have empty collection. This would cover arrays and lists but wouldn't catch all IEnumerable. For those you could do similar `if pi.GetValue(AutomatedFromUser) is IEnumerable ie && ie.Count() == 0){...}` but that is dangerous as it could enumerate a db query. Perhaps a new question is warranted. If this solved your problem, click the checkbox